# Faithful irreducible character and Sylow subgroup

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, representation-theory

I am trying to solve the (very nice) exercise 5.25 from Isaacs, character theory.

Assume that every Sylow subgroup of $G$ has a faithful irreducible character. Show that $G$ has one also.

The indication is to consider $S$ the product of all  of the minimal normal subgroups of $G$ (which is a direct product of simple groups by a classic result) and find $\vartheta\in Irr(S)$ such that $Ker\vartheta$ contains no non-trivial normal subgroup of $G$ i.e. $Ker\vartheta$ is a core-free subgroup of $G$.

Once proven, then $Ker\vartheta^G=(Ker\vartheta)_G=1$ and so $\vartheta^G$ is faithful. I still have to show that $\vartheta^G$ is an irreducible character of $G$.

Comment: You just need to show that the irreducible constituents of $\theta^G$ are faithful. Let $\psi$be such a constituent. Then by Frobenius reciprocity $\langle \theta,\psi_S \rangle > 0$. If $\psi$ was not faithful then it would have a minimal normal subgroup $N$ of $G$ in its kernel, but $N$ is not in the kernel of $\theta$, so we get a contradiction.

Comment: Thanks Derek. Could you please also help me with proving the indication ?

Comment: $S$ is a direct product of elementary abelian $p$-groups $N_p$ and nonabelian simple groups $S_i$. We take $\theta$ to be the tensor product of irreducible characters of these factors. For the nonabelian factors, take any nontrivial character. For $N_p$, we have $N_p \le P \in {\rm Syl}_p(G)$. Let $\chi$ be a faithful irreducible character of $P$. Then for the character of $N_p$, take any irreducible constituent of $\chi_{N_p}$. This is nontrivial on $N_p \cap Z(P)$, which has order $p$ and so its kernel cannot contain any minimal normal $p$-subgroup of $G$.

Comment: Thanks vm Derek. Could I pls ask you to elaborate for the last two sentences ? Why is every irreducible constituent of $\chi_{N_p}$ non-trivial on $N_p\cap Z(P)$ and why does this subgroup have order $p$ ?

Comment: It's nontrivial on $N_p$ because $\chi$ is faithful. The existence of $\chi$ shows that $Z(P)$ is cyclic, and $N_p$ is elementary abelian, so $|Z(P) \cap N_p|=p$.

Comment: Do we need $|Z(P)\cap N_p|=p$? Call $\psi$ an irreducible constituent of $\chi_{N_p}$ as above. If for some prime $p$, $N_p\le Ker \psi$, then $N_p\cap Z(P)\le \psi_{N_p\cap Z(P)}$, contradicting the fact that $\psi_{N_p\cap Z(P)}$ is non-principal.

Comment: You seem to be assuming $N_p$ is a single minimal normal subgroup of $G$ rather than a direct product of several. Any such minimal normal subgroup must intersect $Z(P)$ nontrivially. Then the fact that $Z(P)$ is cyclic means that they all contain the subgroup $N \cap Z(P)$ of order $p$, so in fact $N_p$ is itself minimal.

Comment: Understood. Thanks very much. Last question, I can prove that at least an irreducible constituent of $\chi_{N_p}$ is nontrivial on $Z(P)\cap N_p$ but I don't know how to prove that every irreducible constituent is like that.

Comment: By Clifford's Theorem, the kernels of all of the constituents are conjugate in $G$, which means in this case that they are equal.

Comment: Agreed. Thanks very much for all.